# Html DIV and SPAN tags

Tags: html, css

Can I make DIV tag function as SPAN tag? i.e., removing line-break before and after the DIV tag.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, use CSS

```
display: inline
```

Answer (score 6):

DIVs are block level elements which means they have a default `display:block` - give it `display:inline` (which SPANs have) to override this. Please be a good programmer and do this with CSS not inline styles :)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, generally you can use `display: inline;` but **beware** of the beast...

Make sure you're aware of differences between browsers on `display: inline;` and `display: inline-block;` and when you might want to use which:

http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html

http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

Comment: @annakata, yep, you have to use `display: inline;` in IE but `display: inline-block;` elsewhere for the same effect. Sigh.